# Find completely commented files which are commented by /* */

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, database-project

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207232/find-completely-commented-files). I would like to find all commented files. But in my case `/* */` is a possibility.

Apparently when you write changes to a database project, dropped objects are only commented out instead of deleting the file. I would like to remove all of these commented out files from the project.

Is is possible to find all files which start with `/*` and end with `*/`?

Comment: Are you doing this inside Visual Studio?  Or outside in OS?

Comment: Either way would be fine, I'd just like to be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual studio

Your regex is:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

Use the following options in "find in files" (Ctrl-Shift-F)
[image]

This reference has even more options [ostermiller.com/findcomments.html](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html)
I'm sure you could mod this to find the /// comment as well

Comment: works mostly, but still files with uncommented content are being returned.

Answer (score 0):

Studio allows you to search with regular expressions so you could write a regular expression to find /* at the beginning and */ at the end of any file.  I'm no regex wizard so I'm not sure of the exact syntax.  Maybe something like /*.*/ would work?

Any regex gurus know the proper expression here?