# Find files in Visual Studio Solution with no code (e.g. blank or completely commented out)

Tags: visual-studio

I was going through my solution and found a couple of classes that had been totally commented out. I'd like to remove these from my solution, and get the changes checked into source control.  I assume someone over time has either re factored this code or removed whatever functionality it originally delivered.

I'm just wondering if there are any more class files in my project like this so I can get rid of the garbage.

Comment: Search for files containing comments longer than a bunch of lines. Are you looking for a method to automate this process?

Comment: What command do I run to find the developers who left an entirely commented file in a project, so I can have them deleted!

Comment: I think the other question only found completely commented files (I want blank or completely commented). So it isn't really a duplicate at all.

Comment: If you want to find blank files, most operating systems allow you to arrange files by size.  You can assume the ones taking up no space beyond metadata are probably empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of any such tool available in VS(not third party) but you can find "//" in whole project and manually select files mostly commented, otherwise write a tool(Console App) that scan all files in sub directories and return filenames if 80% of the lines starts with // in a file

Answer (score 0):

Heres a VS macro which find files which start with /* or their length is 1 or less. Of couse you can improve this with "contains // public class" if statement and similiar ones.

```
Public Sub AllFilesWhichAreEmptyOrCommentedOut()
        Dim solution As Solution = DTE.Solution
        For Each prj As Project In solution.Projects
            For Each file As ProjectItem In prj.ProjectItems

                If file.Name.EndsWith(".cs") OrElse file.Name.EndsWith(".vb") Then
                    file.Open()
                    Dim selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection = file.Document.Selection

                    If selection Is Nothing Then
                        Continue For
                    End If

                    selection.StartOfDocument()
                    selection.EndOfDocument(True)

                    Dim content As String = selection.Text
                    If content.StartsWith("/*") Then
                        Log("File " & file.Name & " starts with /*")
                    End If

                    If content.Length <= 1 Then
                        Log("File " & file.Name & " is empty.")
                    End If

                    ' Reset selection back to top
                    selection.StartOfDocument()

                End If

            Next
        Next

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type f -exec sh -c 'grep -vq "^//" {} || echo {}' \;`

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207232/find-completely-commented-files).